# Avoiding duplicating graph in tensorflow (LSTM model)

Tags: python, tensorflow, while-loop, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have the following simplified code (actually, unrolled LSTM model):

```
def func(a, b):
    with tf.variable_scope('name'):
        res = tf.add(a, b)
    print(res.name)
    return res

func(tf.constant(10), tf.constant(20))
```

Whenever I run the last line, it seems that it changes the graph. But I don't want the graph changes. Actually my code is different and is a neural network model but it is too huge, so I've added the above code. I want to call the `func` without changing the graph of model but it changes. I read about variable scope in `TensorFlow` but it seems that I've not understand it at all.

Comment: Yes, `tf.add` adds a new node. Are you calling `func` for new nodes all the time? If yes, the graph must be changed in order to introduce a new op

Comment: @Maxim no, suppose that func is a computation graph. I want to call it inside a for loop. I don't want it changes all the time. I want it to be unchanged.

Comment: I don't understand your case. Why are you calling it in a loop?

Comment: @Maxim Actually it is a very simplified version of my code. I'm trying to implement an LSTM model. In my unrolled version of LSTM, whenever I call the function containing the gate operations, it makes new stuff. I want the model be unchanged but it makes them again and again. Also thanks helping me yesterday. It was really helpful.

Comment: You're welcome! Got you, I'll try to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at the source code of `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`, specifically `_dynamic_rnn_loop` function at [`python/ops/rnn.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py#L647) - it's solving the same problem. In order not blow up the graph, it's using `tf.while_loop` to reuse the same graph ops for new data. But this approach adds several restrictions, namely the shape of tensors that are passing through in a loop must be *invariant*. See the examples in [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) documentation:

```
i0 = tf.constant(0)
m0 = tf.ones([2, 2])
c = lambda i, m: i < 10
b = lambda i, m: [i+1, tf.concat([m, m], axis=0)]
tf.while_loop(
    c, b, loop_vars=[i0, m0],
    shape_invariants=[i0.get_shape(), tf.TensorShape([None, 2])])
```

Comment: if it should be invariant, it means that I can not use None as the batch size or the length of the time series?

Comment: It does accept 'None` statically, but it can't *grow* in any direction easily. Tensorflow checks it at runtime. If you do need to grow the tensor, you have to specify `shape_invariants` and be careful in your body function. In short, `tf.while_loop` is tricky.