# How to operate on tensors in a loop without creating more node in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to do some operation on a tf node in two loops. However, TensorFlow tends to create more nodes to the graph in each iteration of the loop. Is there any way to do multiple operations on a tf node in a Python way, say without creating all the nodes but simply iterate through the loop and do operations?

To give an example with the code below, it seems that TensorFlow creates all the node (xi, xj, and loss here) while going through the loop:

```
def get_marginal_loss(features, labels, threshold, margin):
with tf.variable_scope("marginal", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    xi = tf.get_variable('xi', [], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0), trainable=False)
    xj = tf.get_variable('xj', [], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0), trainable=False)
    loss = tf.get_variable('marginalLoss', [], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0), trainable=False)
assign_op = loss.assign(0), xi.assign(0), xj.assign(0)
for i in range(batch_size):
    for j in range(batch_size):
        if i == j: break
        xi = features[i] / tf.norm(features[i], ord=1)
        xj = features[j] / tf.norm(features[j], ord=1)
        print(xi)
        print(xj)
        dis = tf.norm(xi-xj, ord=2)**2
        print(dis)
        y = 1 if labels[i] == labels[j] else -1
        loss = loss + tf.maximum(margin - y * (threshold - dis), 0)
return loss / (batch_size*(batch_size - 1)), assign_op
```

Comment: See this question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/49114306/712995

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to nodes which are variables - you should use the tf.get_variable() method.
from the [official TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable): "Gets an existing variable with these parameters or create a new one"

Comment: Is there any way to reset the value of the variable at the end of the loop?

Comment: yes - for variable x:
assign_op = x.assign(1) ; 
sess.run(assign_op)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I just tried on it and there is still some problem, I added the code to my question if you could take a look at it.